# Getting a list value for every row (list of ids from another table)

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a quite ordinary table with a foreign key to another table; for example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT table_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE table_b (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  a_id integer,       -- The foreign key
  CONSTRAINT table_b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT table_b_a_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
      REFERENCES table_a (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
INSERT INTO table_a
     VALUES (1, 'First row');
-- 2 entries in table_b which refer to the existing table_a row:
INSERT INTO table_b
     VALUES (11, 1), (12, 1);
```

Now I'd like to have a view which gives me a list of all ids of `table_b` rows which refer to the current `table_a` row:

```
SELECT a.name,
       (SELECT b.id
          FROM table_b b
         WHERE b.id = a.id) AS b_ids
  FROM table_a a;
```

However, the `b_ids` column is empty; I'd like to have some kind of list there, containing the values 11 and 12.

Somewhere I read that subselects can only yield one column (ok for me in this case) **and only one row** (which would explain that the above query doesn't work for me). If this is true - how can this be done instead? Or do I really need to issue `SELECT` requests for every single `table_a` row in my program?

I'd like this to work with PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.3.

Comment: just show ur expected result ?? do you want to get `11 and 12` in a single rows or in two rows ?

Comment: I'd like to have one row, containing `name` = `'First row'` and `b_ids` something like `(11, 12)`.

Comment: You want string_agg(id,',') over (partition by a_id) I guess

Comment: I'd prefer a real list; joining the ids to a comma-separated string might be an acceptable workaround if everything else fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `array_agg` function :

```
SELECT table_a.name, array_agg(table_b.id)
FROM table_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id = table_b.a_id
GROUP BY table_a.name;

┌───────────┬───────────┐
│   name    │ array_agg │
├───────────┼───────────┤
│ First row │ {11,12}   │
└───────────┴───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Any special reason for the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of a subselect?

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
      ,string_agg(b.id::text,',') b_ids 
from table_a join table_b b on table_a.id= b.a_id
group by name
```

Comment: My foreign key is not `NOT NULL`, but this query would omit rows where it is `NULL`, right? Thus, Marths answer is better.